# TCP_INFO on iOS

Tags: ios, tcp

Anyone know if there is a way to get socket stats on iOS, in particular I am interested in congestion window size and rtt? Something like TCP_INFO on linux (http://linuxgazette.net/136/pfeiffer.html)

Comment: What have you tried?  It looks like BSD sockets support `TCP_INFO` so it should work the same.

Comment: I couldn't find TCP_INFO constant anywhere in iOS headers... So... What I have tried is to find anything related to TCP_INFO in headers,  I could only find netinet/tcp_var.h which is not included into iOS SDK...

Comment: Actually Apple have headers available on OSX, but they didn't include them in iOS - they said they will include them into new OS version